# How do you answer these questions regarding the Taylor series method?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, taylor-expansion, approximation

(a) Approximate $f'(x_0)$ and $f''(x_0)$ using the values $x_0-h$, $x_0$ and $x_0 + \alpha h$ $(0 < \alpha)$ by applying the Taylor series method.

(b) Assuming $f(x)\in C^3$, evaluate the approximation error. What is the approximation order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(x_0 + \delta)$ is approximately $f(x_0) + f'(x_0)\delta + \dfrac{f''(x_0)}{2}\delta^2$.

So:

$$\begin{align}
f(x_0 + 0) & = f(x_0) + f'(x_0)0 + \dfrac{f''(x_0)}{2}0^2\\
f(x_0 - h) & = f(x_0) - f'(x_0)h + \dfrac{f''(x_0)}{2}h^2\\
f(x_0 + \alpha h) & = f(x_0) + f'(x_0)\alpha h + \dfrac{f''(x_0)}{2}\alpha^2h^2\\
\end{align}$$

rearranging:

$$
\left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & -h & \frac{h^2}{2} \\
1 & \alpha h & \frac{\alpha^2 h^2}{2}\end{array}\right]
\left[ \begin{array}{c}
f(x_0) \\
f'(x_0) \\
f''(x_0) \end{array} \right] =
\left[ \begin{array}{c}
f(x_0)\\
f(x_0 - h)\\
f(x_0 + \alpha h)\end{array}\right]
$$

Solve the linear system and you approximate $f'(x_0)$ and $f''(x_0)$

Answer (score 0):

The (b) part can be solved with Peano form of the remainder:

If  $\ T_n(x)$ is the n-th Taylor polynomial, then let $R_n = f(x) - T_n(x)$.

From Peano's theorm we know, that $lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{R_n(x)}{{(x-x_0)}^n} = 0$

As far as (a) goes, what can we assume about $f$? Do we know anything about it?

Comment: For (a) the information above is all the information provided. Also could you expand on your answer to part (b) please?